# OS X, Chrome, and Spaces annoyance

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-spaces

I use Google Chrome as my web browser on MacOS X Snow Leopard. I am a keyboard shortcut addict, and I use QuickSilver to create keyboard shortcuts for anything I can. One of the most common things that I do is to open a new web browser window. But I use Spaces frequently to partition my tasks that I am currently working on, and when I open a web browser or web page with a QuickSilver trigger, spaces switches to the last space that I used Chrome on and opens a new tab, which often distracts me for hours because it brings me to a different space and thus a different task.

I can fix this by right-clicking on the Google Chrome icon and clicking the "New Window" option, which opens a new window on the current space. I have tried to compose an AppleScript to do something like this, with no success. It has become a serious problem. Back when I used Firefox, I solved the problem by changing a preference item that says "Always open pop-up links in a new window" or something like that, which was kind of a sledge hammer approach, but it worked. I can always go back to Firefox, but I thought I'd ask my question here first. Anyone with any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution to this problem involves Applescript.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819807/accessing-dock-icon-right-click-menu-items-with-applescript) answer that I got by posting a related question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I agree this is annoying.  You can drag the tab off of the Chrome window, and drag it into the new space (which is what I typically do).

Answer (score 1):

Spaces is transparent to the applications. **If applications don't want to know about Spaces, they don't need to**.

As you pointed out yourself, you have the option in Firefox to open web pages either in the same, frontmost browser window, or a new window. *Since Firefox doesn't know about Spaces, you switch spaces, back to Firefox' frontmost window, in the former setting*. In the latter setting, you open a new window, which can be accomplished on your current space.

**There is most likely no way to get the behavior you want. Your best bet is to find a "sledge hammer" option similar to that in Firefox**.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider looking at how [Chrome's process model](http://blog.marcchung.com/2008/09/05/chromes-process-model-explained.html) is interacting with Spaces.  I am really only guessing, but perhaps one of them will play nicer with Spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I found going to setting in chrome preferences and clicking reset worked - it disables extensions but they can be restarted